# Read a batch by IDs from Mongo in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I have a document collection like:

```
{ "_id":"ABC", "job": {...} }
```

How to read a batch of `Job`s given a collection of `ID`s from Mongo DB in Kotlin?

We search like this:

```
MongoClients.create(clientSettings).use { client ->
    val db = client.getDatabase(dbName)
    val coll = db.getCollection(collName)
    val filter = Filters.`in`("_id", jobs.ids)
    val res = coll.find(filter).map{ it.get("job") /* ??? */  }.asIterable()
    return JobBatch(res)
}
```

Please see `/* ??? */` - How to convert `Document` to `Job` class?